# "Rate Us" dialog effectivness

Tags: mobile, android, ios

On mobile apps, where/When is the best time to popup this "Rate Us" dialog? I know that it may change from game to game, but is there any statistics out there?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack.UX! Check out the [faq] and [about] pages for how to get the most out of this community. You mention general mobile apps, but then say "game to game". Is your app a game? What's the target audience? Do you have an idea of when/where you want to display it? Right now, your question is vague and hard to answer.

Answer (score 4):

It would all depend on the type of app that it is and the type of user that is using the app. The best time to remind the users to rate your app is when they have finished some task. This is the time where they will feel positive about it and they would be willing to rate it.
i.e. If it's a game, display the rating when they have finish a level that is a milestone.
If it's a tracking app, i.e. running app, you can count the frequency and set some rules. i.e. a person runs >X times a week, the app will ask once a month at X point in the app.

I can't give you precise numbers because it really depends on the use of the app. If the user opens the app everyday be careful with showing the pop up too much because users will get annoyed.

What is also good to do is that if the app has asked XX times, never ask again. Let's face it. Users will not rate it in the future if they have been asked 20 times in the past.

Comment: To add to this, I'd think about having an explicit option for "Never ask me this again." Some people could get touchy from even a single repeated ask. -- And also, telling the user that they can voluntarily submit feedback in a menu option somewhere might be a good idea as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are statistics. I usually say that there are 4 key points:

- Ask at the right moment: people are highly willing to rate you if you ask them right after they do some great achievement. Finish one level, gain some points, etc.
- Ask the right question: wording is really important. Make your question/answer sound like it's part of the game instead of "Would you like to rate us? yes / No"
- Make the popup look as part of your app. Basic standard popups are a terrible UX and not converting. While an in-app poll with your own design is way more effective.
- Reward your users. You will double your conversion and boost ratings.

Comment: You say 'there are statistics' yet you don't provide these. Can you link to where you get this information?